# PDFbox is the free version?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

[PDFbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/pdfacreation.html) is that PDFbox is the free version. I have deployed my code using the PDFbox. SO I need to know about the license about that. I need to get those before I provided into other sources. Please assist me on that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for questions on code, not on licenses.

Comment: Personally, I like this question. If you deal with making software you have to deal with licenses.

Answer (score 3):

See a link to main page: https://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html

> Apache PDFBox is published under the Apache License v2.0.

There is a link to the licence there, you can read the terms yourself.
There is, among others:

> 2. Grant of Copyright License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, each Contributor hereby grants to You a perpetual,
>      worldwide, non-exclusive, **no-charge**, royalty-free, irrevocable
>      copyright license to reproduce, prepare Derivative Works of, publicly
>      display, publicly perform, sublicense, and distribute the Work and
>      such Derivative Works in Source or Object form.

Comment: Thanks for replied. But I'm not able to clear with that. Can provide me with more info about that.

Comment: @Saravanan you asked for the license. Krodilko names it and points you to a link to its complete text. So what additional information do you want?

Comment: @mkl yes, what I have to do exactly. I meant I need to get the license as free or need to pay for things.